# What format should I be publishing my videos in?

Tags: iphone, video-streaming, flv

Just wondering what format is accepted as "the best" to have your video content on.  We currently have our videos in FLV format being played by a JW Player.  Are FLV's iPhone compatible or should we be encoding in another format?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FLV video is not supported on the iPhone. H.264 should be you choice if you plan on targeting the iPhone.

If you're looking into streaming the video have a look at Apple HTTP streaming which is supported by the iPhone.
[HTTP Streaming Architecture](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/HTTPStreamingArchitecture/HTTPStreamingArchitecture.html) - Might need Apple ID to view it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the iPhone SDK, You can use -

> Media Player framework to display
>   full-screen video from files in either
>   H.264 (Baseline Profile Level 3.0)
>   format or MPEG-4 Part 2 video (Simple
>   Profile) format.

So I gather that the FLV video is not supported on the iPhone and you should encode the videos in one of these two formats. Also note that only full-screen video playback is supported on the device, with a fade-in transition to the player when video is started.